# add prefix to url using htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

so i am using wordpress and i want to add /news path to my root url,

from :
http://localhost

to :
http://localhost/news

and if i have a post it should be like
[http://localhost/news/%category%/%post-name%](http://localhost/news)

do i need to use htaccess?
here's my htaccess,default wordpress htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

i tried to change the htaccess into :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)$ /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

but it gives me 404.php page
i have noo experience with htaccess

Comment: That rule certainly will rewrite requests to that new URL structure. I suspect however that this question is a miss understanding. That your references (what wordpress sends out as links) do _not_ follow that structure, but still have the ordinary structure `/category/post`. That would explain the 404 status you receive, since you removed the rule that is meant to rewrite those to wordpress' index script. If so then you'd have to change the internal base path of wordpress first or move the installation into a folder of that name.

Comment: I see, so I need to add my wordpress folder into folder called news?

Comment: As said, that would be an option. I cannot say whether that has any other side effects though. Also I am not sure if you can simply move an existing installation (haven't used wordpress for many years now). At least you'd need to reconfigure it to acknowledge that. Alternatively, as said, you could _try_ to simply change the base path inside wordpress and see what links it hands out.